# MSSQL Join between big and empty tables

Tags: sql-server, join, entity-framework, scan

I've got an issue with estimated cost and join predicate :

```
SELECT c.Id FROM Table_A a
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON b.Id_A = a.Id
LEFT JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id
WHERE a.Id = 2500
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Table_A has 50k rows, Table_B is empty, Table_C has 2M rows
The PK and FK indexes exists and the stats are up to date.

But for some reason, SQL Server use a Clustred Index Scan on Table_C.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1G_LnpeU

This is a sample my problem, the prod tables are fare bigger and use too much estimated grant memory because of this issue.

Using a `FORCESEEK` or change the join to `LEFT JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id AND c.Id_B IS NOT NULL` resolve the issue but it's a query (mutliple queries in fact) generate by Entity Framework so I don't have so much control on it.

Is there a way to seek Table_C without changing the query here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to replicate your issue due to you noting that

```
LEFT JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id AND c.Id_B IS NOT NULL
```

improved the query.

**DDL & DML**

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A (id int not null,
                     constraint ClusteredIndex_A primary key (id))

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_A(id)
SELECT top(50000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM MASTER..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..spt_values spt2;


CREATE TABLE Table_B (id int not null,
                      Id_A int 
                     constraint ClusteredIndex_B primary key (id))


-- constraint FK_C_B FOREIGN KEY (id_B) REFERENCES Table_B(id)
CREATE TABLE Table_C (id int not null,
                      Id_B int 
                     constraint ClusteredIndex_C primary key (id),
                     constraint FK_C_B FOREIGN KEY (id_B) REFERENCES Table_B(id))
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_C(id,Id_B)
SELECT top(2000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
NULL
FROM MASTER..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..spt_values spt2;

CREATE INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-B-A] on dbo.Table_B(id_A);
CREATE INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-C-B] on dbo.Table_C(id_B);
```

And as a result, your query is going slow due to all the `NULL` values in the `Table_C` table.

```
SELECT c.Id FROM Table_A a 
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON b.Id_A = a.Id 
LEFT  JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id
WHERE a.Id = 2500 OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Resulting to a starting point close to yours:

[image]

The easiest & best solution here would be changing the query as you pointed out.

```
SELECT c.id
FROM Table_A a 
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON b.Id_A = a.Id 
LEFT  JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id and c.Id_B is not null
WHERE a.Id = 2500;
```

A possible but far from ideal solution would be adding `OPTION(loop join)` with a [plan guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/plan-guides?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
exec sp_create_plan_guide   
@name = N'Guide_1',  
@stmt = N'SELECT c.id
FROM Table_A a 
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON b.Id_A = a.Id 
LEFT JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id 
WHERE a.Id = 2500;',  
@type = N'SQL',  
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = NULL,  
@hints = N'OPTION (LOOP JOIN)';
```

[image]

But the issue with high estimates on `dbo.Table_C` persists & plan guides are a last resort (if even).

Im gonna leave this up so other people can test & replicate your problem using DDL & DML for now. Maybe statistics or indexing could prove a solution that I was unable to find.

Edit

option(FAST 1) produces single row estimates & low cost (for this single example)

```
SELECT c.Id FROM Table_A a 
LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON b.Id_A = a.Id 
LEFT  JOIN Table_C c ON c.Id_B = b.Id
WHERE a.Id = 2500 OPTION (RECOMPILE,FAST 1);
```

[image]

Again not ideal since bigger resultsets will be impacted and other issues might arise.

What also works is inserting one row in `dbo.Table_B`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_B(id,Id_A)
VALUES(1,NULL);
```

& update the stats `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Table_B`

So sql server does not have to join `table_C` to an empty `table_B`

[image]

Or insert -1.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_B(id,Id_A)
VALUES(-1,NULL);
```

What you then could do, is generate the statistics with the 1 row, and create these on the empty `dbo.Table_B`.

By right clicking the database --> tasks --> generate scripts

[image]

Choose table_B

[image]

On advanced scripting options select script out statistics & histograms:

[image]

Save to new query window, next, next, finish.

[image]

And for me I got these statistics:

```
/****** Object:  Statistic [ClusteredIndex_B]    Script Date: 17/01/2020 10:58:36 ******/
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[Table_B]([ClusteredIndex_B]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
/****** Object:  Statistic [NonClusteredIndex-B-A]    Script Date: 17/01/2020 10:58:36 ******/
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[Table_B]([NonClusteredIndex-B-A]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 0x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
GO
```

Deleted all data:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Table_B
```

Reran the two update statistics with stat streams.

[To get a better performing execution plan with correct estimates & results](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1kfPbybU)

Comment: thanks for the answer, and for the DDL & DML.
I will try the plan guide.
I continue searching and I suppose the problem is within the statistics : if I have only 1 match between table_C and table_B, we have the same issue except with a `UPDATE STATISTICS Table_C WITH FULLSCAN`.
I suspect SQL Server to always do a `SCAN` and a `MERGE JOIN` when the sample in the statistics is empty, but I didn't find any explanation over it.

Comment: @Zobix Happy to help. Do watch out with the plan guide. The one posted forces nested loop joins for all executions of the queries. It is also something not easily spotted, document the change if you make any and test the results thoroughly.

Comment: A big thanks : I just tried your edit and it works well. Even without the streams stats :
Doing `UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[Table_B]([ClusteredIndex_B]) WITH ROWCOUNT = 2, PAGECOUNT = 1` AND `UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[Table_B]([NonClusteredIndex-B-A]) WITH ROWCOUNT = 1, PAGECOUNT = 1` solve the problem.